# Proper Reusable Subview with Laravel's Blade Template System

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a login form which I wish to reuse in various contexts. For example, I want a page with only login (www.mysite.com/login), but also want to use the login form on my front page (wwww.mysite.com).

Laravel's documentation proposes the following method to use subviews for a user profile.

```
<!-- Stored in app/controllers/UserController.php -->

class UserController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * The layout that should be used for responses.
     */
    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

    /**
     * Show the user profile.
     */
    public function showProfile()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('user.profile');
    }

}

<!-- Stored in app/views/layouts/master.blade.php -->

<html>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<!-- Stored in app/views/user/profile.blade.php -->

@extends('layouts.master')

@section('sidebar')
    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@stop

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@stop
```

The problem is the subview is 'polluted' with code making it the child of the layouts.master view. Since I want my login form to be reusable in various layouts, I don't want any reference to a particular layout in which it should be used.

I figure I can call it in a view as a view variable:

```
{{ $login }}
```

Then implement it with a controller like this:

```
$this->someview->login = View::make('user.login');
```

And my login view could thus be pure:

```
 <!-- Stored in app/views/user/login.php -->

<form method="post" action="{{ URL::to('/') }}/login" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>credentials</legend>
        <label>
            <span>email</span>
            <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="yourname@email.com" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>password</span>
            <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="password" tabindex="2" required>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

Is this the best way to insert subviews without hardcoding the layout in which it should be used?

I have to be honest, I can see the power in defining layouts for particular views as it provides the possibility to load the view and the system finds the layout automatically, but doesn't that go against the notion of dry coding?

Answer (score 3):

You can *include* any view into another by using the blade `@include` syntax. [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#other-blade-control-structures) (you have to scroll down a bit)

```
@include('user.login')
```

If you want, you can also pass in parameters...

```
@include('user.login', array('foo' => 'bar'))
```

...which are then accessible as variables in the included view

```
{{ $foo }}
```

#### Update

So for example for your login page you would create a `login.blade.php`. (and I'd place the login subview containing the form in a subdirectory. e.g. `partials`)

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    @include('partials.login')
@stop
```

And in your controller action you simply return the login (page) view

```
return View::make('login'); // NOT partials.login
```

And for other pages that need a login form, just do the exact thing.

Comment: Right, but that messes up my layout. The layout is also used for many pages. I want my layout to be agnostic, and my subview also. I'm thinking having a {{ $content }} in layout and using a controller to load my view. No sure if I'm clear.

Comment: Don't put it in the layout. Please take a look at the updated answer

Comment: Hmmm right... I see. Interesting. So that would give me best of both words, being able to call the login view which would load my layout automatically, but still have a clean partial. Thanks a bunch. I didn't understand this partial idea. I marked up your answer.